# IntelliJ IDEA не видит "Hex"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hex

IntelliJ IDEA не видит "Hex", в чем может быть проблема?
Код брал [отсюда](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPOLmvxTxnA)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не хватает библиотеки Apache Commons-Codec. Класс `Hex` [от туда](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html).